# Multi-GPU system PCIe lanes requirements

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

I'm building a multi-GPU machine for scientific calculations. I'm going to pair a Xeon E5-2620v3 CPU with the Asus X99-E WS motherboard to install 3-4 Titan X GPUs. The CPU provides 40 PCIe lanes and the chipset provides additional lanes, so that one can run up to quad x16 setups on a 40-lane CPU. What bothers me is the theoretical performance impact originating from the limited bandwidth. How critical is that for applications with almost 100% GPU-bound loads if GPUs will be constantly loading data from RAM? Should I rather go with 2 CPUs?

Comment: If it’s “constantly loading” at 1KB/s it won’t matter much. So, the answer is of course: It depends. Also, what limited bandwidth?

Comment: @DanielB the number of PCI-lanes (without switches) limits the data bandwidth for the GPUs. It will be constantly loading gigabytes of memory.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the 2×8GT/s QPI is up to the job. Again, you’re not specifying the desired *throughput*. If I’m on ISDN, I can also be “constantly loading gigabytes” of data. You need to consider when and how the data is transferred: Constantly over time or one big transfer every once in a while? How much data is really transferred? What’s the overhead involved in transferring the data?

Comment: @DanielB most likely each card will have to load up to 100 GBs of data every 1-5 seconds.

Comment: Intel ARK says: “Max Memory Bandwidth: 59 GB/s”, so that’s a no. You might want to rethink your endeavor.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that.  Unless your using SLI for CUDA calculations, going forward the maximum amount of GPUs in SLI, is only 2.  It is possible eventually Nvidia might stop supporting 3-way and 4-way for older generations.  So before you purchase $1000 Titan Xs you might reconsider your purchase.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the info, though we don't use SLI. The framework we use address multiple GPUs independently.

Answer (score 1):

Check guides for cryptocurrency mining farms. That is pretty close to your needs. 1x PCIe throughput is enough for the most calculation-related cases. So you can wire (with rizers) up to 8 GPU per motherboard with standard windows drivers.  More gpus require specialized os and drivers support.